# Phone number masking/mapping/translation APIs or services

Tags: nat

Services like Uber provide users with masked phone numbers so that they can communicate directly with one another without exposing their actual phone number. It seems to me a form of network address translation?

Does anyone have services, OSS, API/code examples or SDK links that one might use to set up a similar system?

Primarily this would entail mapping/translating a generated phone number to a user's actual number (behind the scenes), but telemetry style analytics would also be desirable.

Preferably Node Javascript, C#, or Java... but anything is better than nothing!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ricky from Twilio here.

We put together a tutorial on how to build masked phone numbers with Node.js, C#, Java, Python or Ruby:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/node/express

In this Node.js example, here's the block of code that masks a phone call:

```
router.post('/use-voice', twilio.webhook({ validate: false }), function (req, res) {
  from = req.body.From;
  to   = req.body.To;
  body = req.body.Body;

  gatherOutgoingNumber(from, to)
  .then(function (outgoingPhoneNumber) {
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    twiml.play('http://howtodocs.s3.amazonaws.com/howdy-tng.mp3');
    twiml.dial(outgoingPhoneNumber);

    res.type('text/xml');
    res.send(twiml.toString());
  })
});
```

The gatherOutgoingNumber function uses the phone call `from` and `to` to determine who the user is intending to call, once that number is found this code forwards the call to the correct phone number.

It's MIT licensed and hopefully can help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I found what Uber uses... [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/use-cases/masked-phone-numbers)! So that's one option at least